# Storing multiple types of objects in one collection in MongoDB using NoRM

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm

MongoDB is schema-less.  So, I can technically store any number of different types within one collection.  We currently have the need to store multiple objects that inherit from the same base class in one collection.  Is this possible using NoRM?

For example, we have a Person collection, but this person collection contains Fathers that inherit from Person and Mothers that inherit from Person, etc.  We need their Father-specific and Mother-specific properties to be stored and then when they are pulled out of Mongo, we want the appropriate object created.  Is such a thing possible with NoRM?

Comment: Seems norm is no longer supported (i saw on github that latest commit was made on december, 10). So i suggest to move in side of official c# driver. With official driver you can easy do whatever you want above. In additional official driver support all latest mongodb features.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am coming along late to this question, but I was reading some related questions....

I don't know if Andrew is right about NoRM's support status, but it is true that it seems inactive.  However there is a way you can do what you want to do using the 10gen MongoDB C# driver.

[Here's the link.](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Polymorphicclassesanddiscriminators) This works where you have a polymorphic relationship between your classes.